# Displace elements in ElementTree (nest an element into a parallel element)

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to place several (existing) XML-elements <b> into a parallel element <a>, thus

```
<root>
    <a/>
    <b id="one"/>
    <b id="two"/>
</root>
```

becomes

```
<root>
    <a>
        <b id="one"/>
        <b id="two"/>
    </a>
</root>
```

I have tried this:

```
findingA = root.find('a')
for b in root.findall('root/b'):
    findingA.append(b)
    root.remove(b)
```

But these damn <b> won't move, neither with findall nor iter.

Answer (score 0):

You are searching below the `<root>` element, but you use the path "root/b", which does not match. The for loop gets an empty list and does nothing.

---

Edit: this solution applies to the ElementTree implementation in `lxml` only, the moving behavior does not apply for other cases, refer to the other answers in that case.

In lxml, you don't have to remove the elements `b`, appending does not copy the elements.

```
fA = root.find("a")
for b in root.findall("b"):
    fA.append(b)
```

Comment: if you do not remove `b`, the output tree won't be right.

Comment: @LancelodLiu did you actually try this? Appending somewhere else moves the elements for me.

Comment: Thanks mwil.me. Please see my comment under Lancelod's answer. Your code works well, but it leaves the b-elements twice (once as directs children and then as copies inside a). 

The line `root.remove(b)` works well and only removes the original b-elements.

Comment: @Helen Strange, for me there are no copies, it moves the elements. I'm using Python3 and lxml v3.7.3

Comment: I have now built in the solution in my real environment (incl. writing a real xml-file) — and it works. When I comment out the remove line, the subelement b remains at its original position as direct child of root, and its clone appears in the wrapper.

Looking in the spec:
**append(subelement)**
Adds the element subelement to the end of this element’s internal list of subelements.

Ex eventu, I interpret 'add' as copying, otherwise it would have used another word. Seems like as ET cannot move at all. Even the insert function gives me a copy.

Answer (score 0):

`root.findall()` starts from 'root', try this:

```
findingA = root.find('a')
for b in root.findall('b'):
    findingA.append(b)
    root.remove(b)
```

Comment: What version of `lxml` are running? I get "ValueError: Element is not a child of this node." with this.

Comment: I get that error too with lxml. But the question is tagged with "elementtree", not "lxml", so it seems reasonable to assume that the OP is not using lxml.

Comment: @mzjn Aren't we talking about lxml.etree?

Comment: It appears that @LancelodLiu uses ElementTree (http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) and that you (@mwil.me) use lxml (http://lxml.de). These APIs are very similar, but sometimes they behave differently.

Comment: My question was based on: `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`

Both mwil.me's and Lancelod Liu's solutions work. 

1. The append line copies the b-elements inside a. I then have the b-elements twice in the tree.
2. The remove line removes the original b-elements as direct children of root. The newly creatd b-children of a remain.

My original setting was that I just had created the wrapper element a in the tree in the lines above and I got errors like: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'. So I will have to check my workflow.

Thanks for your efforts!